# Passing sharepoint .docx files to microsoft office word web app

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, office-web-components

I just can't figure out how to do it, I have a full file path, but I can't figure out how to get a the microsoft office word web app to open the filepath. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to upload your .docs file to SharePoint in order to use MS Office Web Apps. Follow the following TechNet article on how to [deploy Office Web Apps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx) to verify the installation. Then make sure to [configure the default open behavior for browser-enabled documents](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837425.aspx).

Comment: is there no way to load in a list of documents as a Java Web part and get them to launch in MS Office using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to do it programmatically

```
 /YOURWEB/_layouts/WordViewer.aspx?id= "here is query string (path to the document)"
```

or

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate ID="submit1"  runat="server"   Text="open"  ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/OpeninBrowser.gif"  ClientOnClickScript="OpenWebApps('%Url%'); return false;">

function OpenWebApps(url) {   
    var ext = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);   // here define the extension
    if (ext == 'docx')  
        window.open('<%= Web.Url%>'+"/_layouts/WordViewer.aspx?id="+encodeURI(url));
    else
        alert('Cannot open document with this extension');
}
```